# Sacar % restante de contenedores total

Tags: javascript

Tengo un ejercicio en el que tengo que saber cuantos contenedores necesito para hacer caber una serie de productos (lamparas, sillas y mesas).

Exemplo:

Contenedor lamparas: capacidad 500 // cantidad lamparas: 500
Contenedor sillas: capacidad 500 // cantidad sillas: 500
Contenedor mesas: capacidad 500 // cantidad mesas: 500

Hasta aquí tengo el codigo correctamente implantado.

El tema es que tengo que crear una función donde me diga si hay algún contenedor que no esta al 100% de capacidad y a cuanto esta.

Ex: el contenedor de lamparas esta a 80% de capacidad.

Como se formularia el codigo para que el console.log me diera la capacidad del contendor que no esta lleno?

Gracias

Comment: Para obtener el % ocupado, debes obtener la cantidad de elementos que ya están dentro del contenedor, dividir esa cantidad entre la capacidad total del contenedor y multiplicar el resultado por 100.

Comment: Incorpora a tu pregunta el código que llevas hecho hasta el momento

Comment: Buenas, ya lo solucioné. Calculé el % total de cada contendor y luego a traves de ifs lo compare con el 100% y sacar el resultado.